# Inequality for an linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider in $X=\left ( C\left [ 0,1 \right ],\left \| \cdot  \right \|_{\infty} \right )$ the operator $T$ defined by $\left ( Tf \right )\left ( t \right )=\int_{0}^{t}f\left ( s \right )ds$, where $t \in\left [ 0,1 \right ]$. Show that $\left \| T^n \right \| \leq \frac{1}{n!}$  that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is $\left \| T^n \right \|=\left \| T \right \|^n$?

My attempt:
First, I found $\left \| Tf \right \|_{\infty} \leq 1$ through some inequalities, and then I fixed $f \equiv 1$ in order to get $\frac{\left \| Tf \right \|_{\infty} }{\left \|f \right \|_{\infty} }=1$, therefore $\left \| T \right \|=1$. Now I'm stuck with the inequality above, can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search approach0.xyz for a duplicate question on this site first.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $g(t)=1$ for $t \geq 0$ and $g(t)=0$ for $t <1$. Then $Tf=f*g$. Show  that $T^{n}f=f*g^{(n)}$ where $g^{(n)}$ stands for $g*g*...*g$ ($n-$ fold convolution). Show by direct computation that $g^{(n)}(t)=\frac {t^{n}} {n!}$ for $t >0$ and $0$ for $t <1$. This gives $\|T^{n}\| \leq \frac 1  {n!}$. So $\|T^{n}\|<\|T\|^{n}$ for $n >1$.